# how to pass string object from one fragment to another fragment android?

Tags: android

There is any in built method to pass string or array of string from one fragment to another.
How to pass string object from one fragment to another?

Answer (score 0):

Sending string from a fragment

```
DiagnosticListFragment fragmentS1 = new DiagnosticListFragment();
                            FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                            bundle.putString(Constants.BundleConstants.USER_ID,user_id);
                            fragmentS1.setArguments(bundle);
                            // Store the Fragment in stack
                            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                            transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_parent, fragmentS1).commit();
```

How to recieve in other fragment :

```
final Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        String user_id;

        if(bundle != null) {
            user_id =  user_id = bundle.getString(Constants.BundleConstants.USER_ID);
        }
```